# how to insert variable into jquery select attribute $("[myAttribute='+myAttribute+']").html('is working');

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select and change a div with my own attribute let say myAttribute="1235"

I try this

```
<font myAttribute="1235">Change me !</font>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var myAttribute = 1235;                    
      $("[myAttribute='+myAttribute+']").html('is working');                    
      $("[myAttribute='+myAttribute']").html('is working');                    
      $("[myAttribute=''+myAttribute]").html('is working');                
</script>
```

but they dont work !! if change the code to

```
$("[myAttribute='1235']").html('is working');
```

everthing is ok but i want to use a variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an editor with highlighting :)

Add extra quotes to make it happen

```
$("[myAttribute='"+myAttribute+"']")
```

Comment: Or remove it... `$("[myAttribute="+myAttribute+"]")`

Comment: Quotes around attribute values are required as per the jQuery documentation.

Comment: @ThiefMaster. Check it, it is not.